# Hidden achievements on temple run 2

Tags: temple-run-2

i have completed lvl 10 , feb 2015 , lvl 11 is now open .. No objectives are available but if I go into game centre it shows there are hidden achievements  left to do .. Anyone know what they are ,, I have all the ones listed on the wiki site

Answer (score 1):

There are a maximum of 20 hidden achievements.You need to keep playing the game. Get started to complete the secret achievements by Jumping for no reason. Doing something unique. Going to long distances etc.

The points of the achievements are listed below :-

4 Achievements - 5 Points
4 Achievements - 6 Points
4 Achievements - 14 Points
1 Achievement  - 15 Points
2 Achievements - 22 Points
1 Achievement  - 23 Points
2 Achievements - 25 Points
1 Achievement  - 27 Points
1 Achievement  - 36 Points

Have a good day!

If I have helped you,Please accept this as an answer!

Comment: You forgot the double spaces. In Arqade, we use markdown (and the proper one, compared to Github). If you want to do a line break, you need to put two spaces (ie. `end of line.  `) before breaking the line (pressing enter). | Paragraphs on the other end can just be defined as per normal (pressing space twice).

Comment: You have edited this aytimothy.So If this is accepted as an answer,Will I get the reputation or you or both?

Comment: Only the original poster will get the reputation. As for <2000 rep people, they'll get 2 reputation for the edit (if approved by higher-up peers).The same logic also applies to upvotes; if I upvoted you - You get the reputation, not me. (You made the post first, I merely edited it) | See [this wiki article](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for more information.